# Как сделать лучше фронт часть?

Tags: javascript, вёрстка

Ситуация такова
Есть 22 пунктов слева
Есть слайдер справа( слайдер из фотографии )
При клике на пункт, слайдер должен иметь те фото что относятся к пункту слева

Возникло 2 идеи как реализовать, подскажите, что лучше или может вы предложите что то универсальное

1. Это внутри пунктов сделать скрытые изображения, при клике на него собираем их через JS , удаляем старый слайдер и создаем новый слайдер из тех фото что есть
2. Делать 22 слайдера, и скрыть, при клике показывать и инициаилизировать ( инициализируется лишь один, так как классы везде одни и те же)

Меня именно интересует Front End часть, поэтому про идеи вывода ajaxoм из Базы данных, прошу не советовать

Comment: как вариант, создать под каждый пункт массив фотографий и при клике просто менять массив

Comment: 22 слайдера одновременно подгруженные с фотками... так себе идея. У слайдера должен быть какой-то метод update. Лучше было бы просто переинициализировать текущий, но с новыми фотками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если слайдер переинициализировать не слишком часто, то это вполне приемлемо (учитывая малое кол-во элементов, 22).

```js
const list = document.querySelector('#list'), 
      slider = document.querySelector('#slider'); 
let siema; 
for (let i = 0; i < 22; ++i) {
  const src = `https://picsum.photos/id/${100 + i}/500/300/`; 
  list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
    <li data-src="${src}" data-checked="0">Image ${i}</li>
  `.trim()); 
}
document.body.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (target.matches('#list li')) {
    target.dataset.checked = +!(+target.dataset.checked); 
    updateSlider(); 
  } else if (target.matches('.nav') && siema) {
    siema[target.id](); 
  }
}); 

function updateSlider() {
  siema && siema.destroy(); 
  slider.innerHTML = ''; 
  for (const el of list.querySelectorAll('#list [data-checked="1"]')) {
    slider.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
      <div><img src="${el.dataset.src}"></div>
    `.trim()); 
  }
  siema = new Siema({ loop: true }); 
}
```

```css
html, body, #list { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { background: #444; font-family: sans-serif; }

section, #list { height: 100%; overflow-y: hidden; }

section { display: flex; flex-flow: row nowrap; align-items: stretch; }
  #list {
    flex: 0 0 130px; 
    list-style: none; 
    overflow-y: scroll; 
    border-right: 1px solid #aaa; }

    #list > li { padding: 1rem; color: #ccc; }
    #list > li[data-checked="1"] { color: #aff; }
    #list > li[data-checked="1"]::before { content: '️✔ '; display: inline; }

  #slider { flex: 1 1 auto; align-self: center; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; }
    #slider img { max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; }

  .nav {
    flex: 0 0 auto; align-self: center; 
    margin: 0 1rem; padding: 0.25rem; 
    background: #aaa; 
    cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/siema@1.5.1/dist/siema.min.js"></script>

<section>
  <ul id="list"></ul>
  <span id="prev" class="nav">◀</span>
  <div id="slider" class="siema"></div>
  <span id="next" class="nav">▶</span>
</section>
```

Если хочется обойтись без переинициализации (для экономии ресурсов и сохранения состояния прокрутки) - то очевидно, нужно искать/создавать слайдер с возможностью обновления при добавлении и удалении слайдов. Не все готовые решения это поддерживают.